# Is there any kind of accessibility headers in browsers e.g. sign language

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

Most browsers share the user defined language with the websites they display (e.g. in JavaScript: *navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage*).

But what if your native language is, for example, sign language, or if you require simple language. What if you require high contrast? While font size is by now handled pretty well through responsive web design or browser features, additional requirements are tricky to implement from a browser point of view.

**Are there, so far, any implementations allowing users to automatically send information to a website, indicating additional accessibility requirements?**

My vision would be an additional header send to websites (similar to do-not-track headers), allowing developers to write css media queries depending on those requirements, thereby, hiding or displaying additional elements or increasing contrast on the site.

I am thankful for any kind of advice, hints, or any ongoing discussions on this, or ideas presented to w3c or other institutions.

Comment: Nitpick: You'll still speak, and presumably *read*, some other language than just sign language. Sign language is not a language, it's a medium, like text or audio.

Comment: Sign language is different for most spoken languages (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sign_languages). Please correct me if I'm wrong but since reading sign language requires vision I don't think it is a medium that would increase accessibility for websites (except maybe for audio/video transcripts, but I think those could also be provided more accessible as text instead). Maybe a better example would be accessibility hints for screen readers or braille displays?

Comment: @deceze You are correct, but those written languages are not their native language, sign language is.

Comment: @kapex sign language is the native language of certain individuals, therefore, providing the ability to display certain accessibility features on demand, could provide more inclusive web sites.

Comment: @deceze - The first sentence of the official American Sign Language (ASL) website produced by the US Dept of Health and Human Services reads "American Sign Language (ASL) is a complete, complex language". ASL is a language and not a medium. ASL may be a person's native language, however this is less common. Most ASL speakers have English as their native language and can read and write in English. By contrast "Signed Exact English" (SEE-II) is more of a medium as you describe. SEE-II strives to be an exact representation of English vocabulary and grammar.

Comment: @deceze ASL is a language. Deaf people do not think in words, they do not have the same grammary. They may hardly read. Illiteracy is common among them. Reading english being deaf is like learning to read chinese without sound.

Comment: You're right, I stand corrected. I'll back-paddle my statement to: sign language requires a different medium altogether; it makes little sense to "request a text document in sign language" (as opposed to requesting it in English or French), so is hard to implement in a sensible way I suppose.

Comment: @deceze agreed, video vs text. But the web, or a web resource (in the sense of HTTP), still is the right medium for sign-language, is it not? ASL has a valid IANA subtag `ase`, so I can be passed to a HTTP server just as general American English. Imho it’s not at all hard to implement in a sensible way. It just hasn’t been done, while the standards allow for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are implementations.

Maybe we can keep this list here up to date with web standards:

**Language**

Multiple preferred languages can be passed from browser to server via the `Accept-Language` header.

The [IANA language subtags registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry) actually lists `simple` as a valid variant, as well as Sign Languages like `sgn-CH-DE` for *Swiss German Sign Language*.

**Alternative Author Styles**

A [website can offer several styles for the user to pick](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/alternatives.en.html)

This enables authors to provide pre-set styles for contrast, a font for the dyslexic etc.

```html
<link rel="alternate stylesheet"
 title="High Contrast"
 href="/contrast.css">
```

Since not all browsers offer a convenient way to switch between these styles, typically a widget on the website provides an additional switch.

**User Style Sheets**

While talking about styles: The CSS standard took users' own style sheets into account, giving them the highest specificity in the cascade.

Usually, this stylesheet is manipulated by means of browser settings. Some I can think of:

- font-family
- default font size
- minimum font size
- link colours

**User preference media queries**

These are [system/browser settings about the user's preferences](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-5/#mf-user-preferences) that are available to web authors as media queries.

Examples are:

- `prefers-contrast`
- `prefers-color-scheme`
- `prefers-reduced-motion`

```css
@media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion) { }
```

---

However, we need to consider support for these features, as well as awareness among users. We need to balance education vs. convenience.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing seems similar to the HTTP header for `Accept-Language`.

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-priorities

> The HTTP request carries language preference information in the
>   `Accept-Language` header. If the server is set up to return alternate
>   versions of a page or resource in more than one language, and the
>   language you prefer is available, it will go through a process known
>   as HTTP content negotiation to find content in the language(s)
>   indicated in the HTTP request. If there is only one version of a page
>   on the server, that version will be retrieved. If none of the
>   languages you request are available, the server should be set up to
>   return a default language choice.

Comment: Thanks, i actually did not know that the browser sends multiple language flags, it could be an interesting hack to use this feature to send an additional language flag for sign language which websites can then use. I will further investigate this idea and get back to your comment.